# Como mostrar la gráfica de barras con el valor más alto en chart para angular

Tags: angular, echarts

En mi proyecto de angular Requiero de poner en primer lugar la gráfica con el valor más alto, agregué en mi código `max: 'dataMax'` en mi archivo .ts pero no veo que se muestre la gráfica como se requiere, estoy usando la librería de apache echarts

código :

```
this.options = {
      xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: xAxisData,
        axisLabel: {
          fontSize: 12,
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          color: '#000'
        },
        axisLine: {
          show: false,
          lineStyle: {
            color: '#000'
          }
        },
        axisTick: {
          show: false
        },
      },
      yAxis: {
        show: false,
        type: 'value'
      },
      grid: {
        containLabel: true,
        top: '35%',
        left: '1%',
        right: '8%',
        bottom: '3%'
      },
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba cambiar `data: xAxisData` por `data:xAxisData.toSorted((a,b)=>b-a)`